# Irrelevant websites in nginx access logs

Tags: logging, nginx

In my nginx-access logs I see entries like

X1X.X2X.2X.2X1 - - [14/Jun/2016:23:06:35 -0400] "GET http://www.qidian.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13191 "http://www.qidian.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
There are many like these and they are not at all related to my website
Is this something I should worry about?
Can anyone explain what exactly happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referer spam. nginx has some documentation here:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/refererspam/

> Referer spam is where someone will hit your site with the referer
>   section of the browser request set to be a site they want to drive
>   traffic to. The idea is to have links to those sites how up in any
>   public stats pages you may have - which are common for blogs and
>   forums.

You'll need the ngx_http_referer_module module to block this; refer to the documentation for the right details for your version of nginx.